# Multi series charting

Tags: javascript, excel

I am trying to create a timeline chart in a different way. Looking for suggestions on which one to use to get the best out of it in javascript world.

My problem is to plot clickable milestones with some text on the Y axis and months on X axis. I also have to show horizontal bars against text strings filled with colour and those milestones plotted on the bar as small circles or diamonds.

Hope I am clear. Can any one throw light on plotting this kind of map either in Excel or Javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks for the response. I agree, but that's the requirement I got. So far, it looks close to my requirement. https://timeglider.com/widget

Answer (score 0):

It may be overkill, but this looks like the best solution, but it does neatly fit your request of timing on x axis, label on y, [TimelineJS](https://github.com/NUKnightLab/TimelineJS)

It's pretty customize-able too to get it how you want.

Comment: Explored this too. Thanks for the response. https://timeglider.com/widget/ looks closer to my requirement - removing Y axis and some how managing with only X axis.

Answer (score 0):

Finally wrote excel based chart and started filling cells with colors etc based on custom logic. Thanks everyone for all your responses.